# Does $\int^{\infty}_{0}pa^{p-1}1_{\{|f|>a\}}(x)da=\int^{|f(x)|}_{0}pa^{p-1}da$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

> Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for $p\in [1,\infty)$. Show that $$\|f\|_p=\left(\int^{\infty}_{0}pa^{p-1}m\{|f|>a\} \right)^{1/p}$$

My attempt:

We can use Fubini's theorem in the following way:
\begin{align*}
\int^{\infty}_{0}pa^{p-1}m(\{|f|>a\})da&= \int^{\infty}_{0}pa^{p-1}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}1_{|f|>a}(x)dx\right)da \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\int^{\infty}_{0}pa^{p-1}1_{\{|f|>a\}}(x)dadx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left(\int^{|f(x)|}_{0}pa^{p-1}da\right)dx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f|^p
\end{align*}
Then taking the $p$th root of both sides gives us the desired inequality.

---

My main concern is if changing the bounds as I did is correct. Any help/critique is much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, your solution is good. For a further clarification, notice that $$\mathbf{1}_{\{|f|>a\}}(x) = \mathbf{1}_{\{|f(x)|>a\}}. $$

Comment: Would $1_{\{|f(x)|>a\}}$ be considered a function of $a$?